# How to evaluate this multivariate limit?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help with a multivariable limit. the limit is this:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(\infty,\infty)} \frac{ x^2 + y^p}{1+x+y},$$

where $p>1$.

Alternatively, it would be enough to have a solution to the following:

$$\lim_{x+y\rightarrow\infty} \frac{ x^2 + y^p}{1+x+y}.$$

Intuitively, the function above the ratio is kind of a paraboloid, which should grow faster to infinity when compared to the plane below. Hence i aspect the result to be $+\infty$. However i have some doubts about this intuition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...and $\;\sigma\;$ is...?

Comment: A nonzero constant, edited

Comment: the limit does not exist if there isn't any more relation between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Well x is the L^2 norm of the derivative of a function and y is the modulo of the the function evaluated in 1... This could help?